# React hook form Rendering too many times

Tags: reactjs, forms, rendering, react-hook-form

I am trying to do something like this.
When user Click on Edit Button then Form fields will appear and user can edit the data. otherwise user can only view the data.
I facing the trouble, when user don't want to edit the form and click on cancel button then page start rendering as many times as the page have total form fields.

On my original form I have 80+ form fields and when user click on cancel button page becomes very slow.

When I remove
ref={register}
from my page then form don't render to many times, but form does not submit with the data.
Is there any way to stop extra rendering?
Here is my code and logic.

Thanks for your attention.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Test() {
   const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
   const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
   const onSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
};
return (
<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    {console.log("I am redering.")}
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <a
        href=""
        onClick={(e) => {
          setEdit(!edit);
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        {edit ? "Cancel" : "Edit"}
      </a>
      {edit && (
        <p>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            ref={register}
            placeholder="Email"
          />
        </p>
      )}
      {edit && (
        <p>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstname"
            ref={register}
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
        </p>
      )}
      {edit && (
        <p>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastname"
            ref={register}
            placeholder="Last Name"
          />
        </p>
      )}
      {edit && (
        <>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="contact[]"
            id="contact-one"
            value="1"
            ref={register}
          />
          <label htmlFor="contact-one">One</label>
        </>
      )}

      {edit && (
        <>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="contact[]"
            id="contact-two"
            value="2"
            ref={register}
          />
          <label htmlFor="contact-two">Two</label>
        </>
      )}

      {edit && <button type="submit">Submit</button>}
      {edit === false && (
        <>
          <p>{`My First Name`}</p>
          <p>{`My Last Name`}</p>
          <p>{`My Email address`}</p>
          <p>{`My Contacts`}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </form>
    <a
      className="App-link"
      href="https://reactjs.org"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
    >
      Learn React
    </a>
  </header>
  </div>
 );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

This is a function call, which means this gets called immediatelt the form is created on the DOM, your event listeners need to take a reference to the function which will then get called when the event occurs, to do that you wrap this function call in another anonymous function. Then the function will get called when the submit event occurs. So you need to do this

```js
<form onSubmit={()=>{handleSubmit(onSubmit)}}>
```

Also since this is a submit event, you might want to stop the default behaviour which refreshes the page. Like this

```js
<form onSubmit={(ev)=>{
  ev.preventDefault()
  handleSubmit(onSubmit)}}>
```

### Update

I did not look at the JSX properly. There are a few things you are probably doing wrong

1. using ref to get input values rather than state
2. when taking in any kind of input you want to convert those fields into control components [Officila docs on controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)
   I suggest you understand this and state first, that will help you a lot. React docs still uses class components in example code but simply use use state instead of this.state for state varibales

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the form tag as you mentioned but still having the same issue.

Comment: on your onClick you might wnat to prevent the default behaviour first, ie do preventDefault first

Comment: OnClick of my cancel button, i am already doing this. 
<a
        href=""
        onClick={(e) => {
          setEdit(!edit);
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >

Comment: do e.preventDefault() first, event though that should not be the cause of ifinite re-rendering. It's just good practice. You might want to look at the error on your browser first and then look into your register ref and handleSubmit functions. Also I just realised you are passing the same ref to every element. You probably do not want to do that

Comment: You are right. 
I did e.preventDefault() first (for best practices). But rendering issue is still there.

Comment: actually I just realized you are doing handleSubmit(onSubmit) , onSubmit here is not a variable. Also if you are using refs to get values from your inputs into the submit function that is not what you want to do. I will update my answer